# Can I deploy a SSRS report (.rdl) on a PowerBI online Workspace?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

Is it possible to run a SSRS report from within a PowerBI online Workspace? I have a premium subscription and thought since Oct it is possible but when I try Get data i get an error saying "This file isn't supported". I don't want to install an on premises Report Server.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, at the moment its not possible. Take a look here for the roadmap. Your problem is mentioned a litte bit below [RoadmapPowerBI](https://insightsquest.com/2018/03/24/power-bi-roadmap-update/). Maybe this will help as well [PinReportingServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pin-reporting-services-items-to-power-bi-dashboards?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: That looks very promising. Does anyone know when this feature is likely to be rolled out?

Answer (score 0):

you can deploy either to share point and they will run. Ofcouse SSRS will go as a sql server report and powerBI/Tableau will go as webpart. we have deployed both at my last client as p.o.c.